# Fluent Mapping - CsvHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, automapper, fluent

I'm using the CsvHelper library built by Josh Close.  I thought the datasource where I'll be obtaining the .csv files had a way to mask or 'alias' the column headers with proper naming convention.  Unfortunately that's not going to be the case so I'd like to use the Fluent Class Mapping but I'm unclear as to how to implement it.

I built the below class(simplified for this post)

```
 public class PaymentType
{
    public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The below method in another class downloads and saves the file

```
private string DownloadDS(string getURL, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //CSV path
            string url = getURL;

            //Where to save and retrieve CSV file
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ImportedFiles\\" + fileName;

            //Download file and save it 
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFile(url, path);



            return path;
        }
        catch
        {



            return "";
        }

    }
```

This method then updates the db

```
 private void UpdateDB(string path, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //read in file with CsvReader object and output to an enumerable object
            var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
            var importedPaymentTypes = csv.GetRecords<ImportPaymentTypes>();

            //Save each payment type record to the db.  If record exhsists, update it, if not, add it.


           ...

        }
        catch
        {
            ...


        }

    }
```

I stripped out some of the logging and db logic to shorten the code snippets.  I read up on the Fluent Mapping but I'm confused on how to implement it?  I understand that I have to build a class, but how do you reference/configure the use of the mapper class?

Here's an example from Josh's site;

http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#reading-reading-all-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the mapping section. http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping

You register the mapping by doing:

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PaymentTypeMap>();
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh and thanks for building such an awesome library!  Just so that I'm clear, I build the map class then place the above line of code inside the class I want to map the file to?  e.g. "using csv.Configuration..."?

Comment: The above line just needs to come before calling `csv.GetRecords`. The mapping just has to be created before you read.

Comment: Josh,  If you have a file that has say 50 columns but you only need 5.  Can you use the map class to only map to say index 0, 3, 6, 9 and 10?  Will it disregard the other columns?

Comment: Yes. It will only use what you have in your map. For future reference, if you want to use everything and just change a couple, in your map you can do `AutoMap();` and then just change the few properties that aren't default.

Comment: AutoMap() uses order of index in the file to map to order of properties in the class?

Comment: If you have headers on (the default), it'll use the names of the properties. If headers is off, it'll use the order the properties are in the file. Note: The order is not guaranteed by .NET definition. Every MS implementation of the .NET framework I've used has been in that order, but just keep that in mind.

Comment: Whats the proper way of reflecting the code again in this post so as to not mess up the original issue and answer?  I ran into another snag with the AutoMap() and its easier to show the solution than to try and explain.  A new post?